# Git command to do a pull and put my changes at the top without stashing?

Tags: git, git-stash

Everytime I have to get the latest changes from the repo I have to stash my changes then do a pull and then unstash my changes again, this process gets very tedious when there's a lot of people working on the project and you have to do this many times a day.

I was wondering if there's a git command that does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing a normal `git fetch` followed by `git rebase --autostash`?

from `man git-rebase`:

```
--[no-]autostash
       Automatically create a temporary stash before the operation begins, 
       and apply it after the operation ends. This means that you can run
       rebase on a dirty worktree. However, use with care: the final stash 
       application after a successful rebase might result in non-trivial
       conflicts.
```

Comment: What happens if I do get a conflict with what I fetched? Is the work in progress going to be lost?

Comment: Fetching does not lead to conflicts like `pull` does, because it only downloads refs and objects without doing a merge.  Though as mentioned in the man page, you might get a conflict when re-applying the stashed changes

Comment: Yes, I guess that's what I meant when the stash is applied, is that going to be lost in case of a conflict?

Comment: At least for me with git version 2.5.0 (don't know if this is always the case) it creates a stash called `autostash` so you don't lose your work in case of unsolvable conflicts, just go back to the pre rebase commit and do `git stash apply`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell alias or a git command alias to do this.

```
[alias]
    update = !git stash save -u && git pull && git stash pop
```

I threw `-u` in there to stash untracked files as well in case the pull adds them.

Comment: The problem with this is that if there's any conflict when you unstash your changes they will get lost and if you do apply you will end up with list of stashes.

Comment: @SaulOrtega They won't get lost. `git stash pop` will only delete the stashed entry if it successfully applies.  If there is a conflict, your changes will remain in the stash. From [the git-stash manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) `"Applying the state can fail with conflicts; in this case, it is not removed from the stash list. You need to resolve the conflicts by hand and call git stash drop manually afterwards.`"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such a command (maybe someone else does...*Edit: Great recommendation Schwern!*)

However, are you working from a feature branch? If not, I highly recommend adding them to your project's git workflow. It would reduce the number of times you need to update your local branch because theoretically you would have less people per branch.

I've found this git workflow reference useful in the past: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: This answer might be better as a comment. While using a feature branch is a good practice, it doesn't change how often you have to update.  It changes it from keeping the local copy up to date to keeping the feature branch up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [git-up](https://github.com/aanand/git-up), which does exactly what you're asking (and some more).

It does the following:

- Fetches all of your local branches
- Rebases (instead of merges) any incoming changes in all of your local branches that have an associated remote branch
- Local changes are stashed/unstashed before/after the rebase

I have been using this a lot, it's perfect for keeping a repo in sync without manually checking out branches, stashing, popping, etc.

You install it using

```
gem install git-up
```

and then you use it in any Git repo using

```
git up
```

That's all...

Comment: Thanks @nwinkler , I'm already using git-up but when I want to pull and I have changes that I haven't commited yet I get an error that I have to stash my changes or commit them before I pull so I don't lose my changes.

Comment: Mh, I just tried it with some unstaged changes, and it worked flawlessly. Git-up stashed the changes, then merged the incoming changes, and then unstashed my unstaged changes. I'm using this all the time...

Comment: Let me do it again and let you know what's specific error I get.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm doing it right. One you have all the commits ready to push you just select push or is there any step that I'm missing?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Git up and pull are about getting updates from a remote repo. Pushing means sending your updates to the remote repo. Not sure what information you're really after...

Comment: No, I'm using the one linked in my answer. It's a command line tool. Give it a try, it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Running `git pull --rebase` may be what you are after.

> `-r`
> `--rebase[=false|true|preserve]`
>
> When `true`, rebase the current branch on top of the upstream branch after fetching. If there is a remote-tracking branch corresponding to the upstream branch and the upstream branch was rebased since last fetched, the rebase uses that information to avoid rebasing non-local changes.
>
> When set to `preserve`, rebase with the `--preserve-merges` option passed to `git rebase` so that locally created merge commits will not be flattened.
>
> When `false`, merge the current branch into the upstream branch.
>
> See `pull.rebase`, `branch.<name>.rebase` and `branch.autoSetupRebase` in [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) if you want to make `git pull` always use `--rebase` instead of merging.

You mentioned that you are working in this branch with other developers, so heed the warning from the end of that section of documentation.

> **Note**
> This is a potentially *dangerous* mode of operation. It rewrites history, which does not bode well when you published that history already. Do not use this option unless you have read [git-rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) carefully.

Comment: Nope, I get this error: Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.

Comment: Right: create a work in progress commit, `git pull --rebase`, and keep moving forward. When you are ready to share your commits, clean up *unpublished* history as desired.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you, when you say "create a work in progress commit" are you saying stash your changes?

Comment: @SaulOrtega What he means by a "work in progress" commit is to commit unfinished work (a practice to be avoided, even in Git), pull, then continue working.  Then later before you push to share your changes, do a `git rebase -i` to fix that "work in progress" commit. If this sounds needlessly complicated and easy to forget, it is.  Stashing, pull, unstash is a much better practice.  While using `--rebase` is a good idea, it doesn't apply to your problem.